# How do you wire a light fixture with only black and white wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, barn

How do you wire a light fixture if from a light fixture that was already there and I have a white wire with smaller wires inside to use to install. The 2 wires are black, and one white wire. Why isn't there a red wire?

Comment: You only need a white and black (green maybe for ground).  A red or other colors are there for auxiliary functions like a fan.  Can you give a better description or picture?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're talking about, please consider editing the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking an educated guess that might change if I get more info.  If everything was working before...

- take the smaller wires off of the white wire and connect your white light fixture wire to it
- connect your black light fixture wire to both black wires - twist them all together
- if your light fixture has a red wire it goes with the black - if it is meant to do a different function (like control a fan) - then you need to run an extra wire up to it for that (12/3 - which has black, white, ground-nothing, and red).